# Need a hint regarding this question...

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, polygons

In how many ways can we select three vertices from a regular polygon having $2n+1$ sides ($n>0$) such that the resulting triangle contains the centre of the polygon?

Comment: [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OkmNXy7er84), while tackling a somewhat different problem, may help you think about this "triangle containing the center" condition in a different way that makes things much easier to count.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** When we fix a vertex of the $(2n+1)$-gon, we can assume that there are $n$ vertices on *left* of the fixed vertex and $n$ vertices on the *right*. In order for the resulting triangle to contain the center of the polygon, we need to choose three vertices such that when we fix *every* vertex one by one, we should have:

- $1$ vertex on the left of fixed vertex, $1$ vertex on the right of fixed vertex (and in this case, the last vertex will be the fixed vertex) OR
- $2$ vertices on the left, $1$ vertex on the right OR
- $2$ vertices on the right, $1$ vertex on the left.

It might not be so clear with words so I will give an example from enneagon ($9$-gon with $n = 4$):

[image]

Suppose we choose the vertices $A$, $D$ and $E$. Then when we fix $C$, $A$ is on the right of $C$; $D$ and $E$ is on the left of $C$ so it may seem like argument holds (by second case). However, I said "fix *every* vertex one by one" so for example when we fix $A$, both $D$ and $E$ is on the left of $A$ therefore $\Delta ADE$ doesn't include the center. But, if we choose $A$, $F$ and $E$, whichever vertex we fix, we will see that one of the three cases above will hold. So $\Delta AFE$ includes the center.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Distribute the remaining $2n-2$ vertices to the $3$ gaps between the chosen vertices. Find the number of ways to distribute them such that each gap contains no more than $n-1$ vertices. (because if a gap contains $n$ or more vertices, the centre of the polygon would be outside the triangle.)